# Sliding Exterior Patio Door air gap

Tags: doors, sliding-glass-door

I had a contractor install sliding patio doors in 2 different areas in my house. The first area the patio doors fit perfectly; however, in the second area there is a gap that leaks air. There is an overlap between the moving door and the fixed door where the two doors should meet up and this is where the leak is occurring.

Does anyone have any tips to close this gap? I have attempted to adjust the tilt screws on the door and it helped close part of the gap but not completely and have pulled out the fixed and sliding door to make sure there are no obstructions behind it causing it to stop short.

Comment: You might want to check to ensure the rollers are adjusted properly (though this should have been done at the factory given they knew the track clearance between the fixed and sliding frames...perhaps the rollers were installed backward?)

Comment: Isn't there a soft flap seal which in the closed position reaches from the back of the slider and seals against the middle frame of the fixed panel?

Comment: Hi Jim, unfortunately no. That's where the air is leaking. The weatherstrip seal does not reach the middle frame of the fixed door leaving a gap for air to come through, so during winter months there is a pretty strong draft.

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your response. I will check out the rollers again to see if anything is off, but I did check them the first time around. Thank you.

Comment: Are these doors custom, made to order? If there is a flap on the slider (projecting toward the fixed glass) and (when the slider is closed) this flap is not reaching the frame of the fixed glass by ~ 1/2", then you could put adhesive weatherstripping on the frame of the fixed glass to fill in this gap. But really, this should not be happening.  Are you sure nothing is preventing the door from closing fully?

Comment: Is the frame of this door aluminum? Are the two units (the one that seals and the one that doesn't) exactly the same dimensions? Did the installers have to cut down the track to make the door fit? Or did it fit as it came from the manufacturing plant?

Comment: Exactly. That flap is not reaching the flapping on the fixed door to lock the air out. I'm going to remove the doors from the frame to see if there are any obstructions again, but there wasn't the first time. Unfortunately, I don't know much about whether they are custom made or whether the tracks were cut down because I trusted the contractor with that and he left the job. I do know that they are not aluminum. My fear is that they were custom made and he only measured one opening leaving one perfect and the other with the air leak.

Comment: How wide is the gap you must fill? Is the sliding door on the outside or the inside? Could you fill the gap with stick-on foam weatherstripping?

Comment: It's about 1/2" gap. I'm planning to try out the stick-on foam stripping because I don't really see any other options.